# Error when using CONVERT while SELECTing from OPENJSON

Tags: sql, json, t-sql, sql-server-2017

Given a variable `@PartsData` that is a `VARCHAR(MAX)` and contains a set of json data, this query works fine:

```
SELECT 
       *
FROM OPENJSON(@PartsData)
        WITH (
            PartId INT 'strict $.PartId', 
            ....
            CultureName VARCHAR(3) '$.CultureName',
            PartDescription VARCHAR(2000) '$.PartDescription'
        ) A
```

But, suppose I want to transform some of the data as I open it from the jason:

```
SELECT 
       *
FROM OPENJSON(@PartsData)
        WITH (
            PartId INT 'strict $.PartId', 
            ....
            CultureName VARCHAR(3) '$.CultureName',
            PartDescription VARCHAR(2000) '$.PartDescription'
            PhraseHash UNIQUEIDENTIFIER CONVERT([uniqueidentifier],hashbytes('MD2',concat('$.PartDescription', '$.CultureName'))
        ) A
```

On this, I get:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.

This works okay, but I need  the calculated value in the original `WITH` so I can join on it:

```
SELECT 
       *
       , CONVERT([uniqueidentifier],hashbytes('MD2',concat(CAST(A.PartDescription as NVARCHAR(max)),A.CultureName))) AS PhraseHash
FROM OPENJSON(@PartsData)
        WITH (
            PartId INT 'strict $.PartId', 
            ....
            CultureName VARCHAR(3) '$.CultureName',
            PartDescription VARCHAR(2000) '$.PartDescription'
        ) A
```

Comment: Can't you take the last query that "works okay" and put that in a sub-select and `Join` that back to the `OPENJSON` with the Converted column. Or use a `CTE` and `Join` that back to the `OPENJSON`.

Comment: Yes, and that will work. But I was hoping to avoid that and find a shortcut :)

Comment: @CaseyCrookston CONVERT has no place in there. `OPENJSON` is meant to parse JSON strings, not apply functions. That's the job of SELECT, CROSS APPLY etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WITH`-clause is not the right place for this, but you can use a `CROSS APPLY` to compute the needed value *row wise* and use this value in a join. Something along this sample:

```
DECLARE  @tbl TABLE(ID INT,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1020,'Values 10 and 20')
,(2030,'Values 20 and 30');

DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'{
    "rows":
     [{"id":"1","val1":"10","val2":"20"},
      {"id":"2","val1":"20","val2":"30"},
      {"id":"3","val1":"20","val2":"30"},
      {"id":"4","val1":"40","val2":"30"}
    ]
  }';

  SELECT *
  FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.rows')
  WITH(id INT,val1 NVARCHAR(10),val2 NVARCHAR(10)) A
  CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(CONCAT(A.val1,A.val2) AS INT)) B(ConcatenatedAndCasted)
  INNER JOIN @tbl t ON t.ID=B.ConcatenatedAndCasted;
```

For your next question: Please try to set up a MCVE (like I've done above) yourself. Add sample data and the expected output. Add your own attempts and explain, why your output is not fullfilling your needs. This will help much more than a thousand words...

### UPDATE

You can retrieve a derived table from your JSON data too like here:

```
  WITH JSON_Data AS
  (
  SELECT *
  FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.rows')
  WITH(id INT,val1 NVARCHAR(10),val2 NVARCHAR(10)) A
  )
  SELECT * FROM  @tbl t
  INNER JOIN JSON_Data jd ON t.ID=CAST(CONCAT(jd.val1,jd.val2) AS INT);
```

In fact there are various approaches using CTEs, sub-queries, applies, or even temp tables. Which one is the best for you, is a matter of row count and your needs...